# Can I answer a question after the user clarifies it in a comment?

Tags: discussion

I often see questions that need clarification.  I know that it is recommended to not answer these until they are made clear. Often, however, the clarification comes through the OP posting a comment on his/her question, as opposed to editing the question itself.

In these cases, is it considered acceptable to answer the question, or is it better to wait for the question itself to be edited to include the clarifications?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Why not do both?  Edit the question with the new clarification detail **and** answer the question based on that clarification.

Comment: It's slightly harder to do the edit when you don't have edit privileges but in general yes... I might be inclined to leave the OP a comment saying "thanks... I know what you mean now - that helps me or others answer your question - would you mind making an `[edit]` to your question including that so it doesn't get lost in comments?" - or similar - I'm sure people already have better auto-comments than that :)

Comment: There's even badges for editing a question then answering.  For example: [explainer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4368/explainer)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jIrnh.gif

Comment: @JonClements "inlined OP's clarification from comment" edit comment may be enough to get edit accepted...

Comment: @Alexei *may be enough*... indeed.